# A tricky trigonometric integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can I evaluate
$$I = \int_0^{\pi / 2} 5x \sin(6x) \cos (9x^5) \,\textrm{d}x$$

without Computer Algebra Systems? Mathematica fails to find the value of $I$ and RIES isn't very helpful too. I've tried expanding the function under integral sign into power series with no results.

If it's too hard, I will be satisfied with

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x \sin x \cos (x^2) \,\textrm{d}x$$

or anything like that.

Comment: Is the argument of the cosine $9x^5$ ?

Comment: @mikevandernaald well, yes.

Comment: the solution to the second one is a Fresnel integral

Comment: Mathematica answer  $$\frac{5}{18}\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\left( -\cos \left[ 1 \right]\left( FresnelS\left[ \frac{-2+3\pi }{\sqrt{2\pi }} \right]+FresnelS\left[ \frac{2+3\pi }{\sqrt{2\pi }} \right] \right)+\left( FresnelC\left[ \frac{-2+3\pi }{\sqrt{2\pi }} \right]+FresnelC\left[ \frac{2+3\pi }{\sqrt{2\pi }} \right] \right)\sin \left[ 1 \right] \right)$$